# Python: How to link back & front on website for Word/PDF templates?

Tags: python, web, python-docx, office-automation, auto-generate

I'm a newbie and I'm learning by building a website for templates.

My goal is to have good UI that summarises all inputs to pre-populate a Word template (e.g. invitation for event)

How should the flow be? I currently think it's probably i) UI to CSV, ii) CSV to feed Word template, iii) Code generates the end file in PDF. Doesn't this become too messy with large files?

My questions:

1. I started with the the python-docx library - is this fine?
2. Is the flow I described above correct? How should I do this?

Thank you so much!!

python-docx library - does not work as well as I thought as I question how to link the website to it in a scalable way

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you saying you want to generate PDF files from some database of information?  There are lots of ways to do that without involving Word, including the `reportlab` module.  If you absolutely need to use Word for the template, then the easiest path is to invoke Word itself to do the mailmerge.  Word has an extensive object model API.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. My bad. I want to:
1) I build some Docx template
2) I link variables in python 
3) I upload to website
4) I fix UI
5) People use website to input data (e.g. First Name, Last Name)
6) Website generates Docx file or PDF

Does this help?

I am not building it just for the functionality but I also must link it to a website

Comment: OK, but you didn't my reply.  You're focusing on the path you've chosen without thinking about the overall problem.  If your web server runs Windows and has Word installed, then you can use COM to control Word to do the mailmerge directly.  If not, then Word is not the right choice.  There are several packages for creating PDF files directly.

Comment: Thank you both. Sorry, I’m new to this. Let’s ignore PDF for now in this case. I understand some subscription may be required but how could I make a website where I have pre-loaded Word templates, which are updated and generated after people provide inputs on the website? In python alone, this works with python-docx but how to make the link with the website?

Comment: You might be better off not using word templates at all, and switch to HTML. You'd have much more flexibilities. My advice would be learn HTML, CSS, JS, maybe a templating engine like jinja if you're using python, then how to generate pdf from HTML if you need a pdf as an output

Comment: Ok, I see. So a combination of HTML, CSS, JS and Jinja would let me generate a website where people input data and it generates a PDF/Word they can download? I assume it requires more plugins?